# postgresql для разработчика С++

Tags: c++, postgresql

Всем привет. Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться в ситуации. Как часто БД postgresql используют при разработке на С++? Могут ли возникнуть какие-либо сложности при её использовании? С какой БД будет легко перейти на postgresql?

Comment: Так это скорее наоборот — как часто C/C++ используют для разработки под postgres. Используют, в основном для каких-нибудь встраиваемых в сервер БД штуковин. Какие-либо сложности возникают при использовании любой СУБД. Просто так перейти ни с одной БД ни на какую другую, видимо, не возможно.

Comment: Вопрос состоял в том, чтобы перейти с точки зрения изучения конкретной СУБД  на другую или же в том, чтобы на сервере, на котором крутится, к примеру, база данных Orable, разместить Postgre?